# WebAPI Serialization problems when consuming Recurly Rest API which returns XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to the ASP.Net Web API. I'm trying to interact with the Recurly REST based API and I am getting errors like below during my ReadAsAsync call which is the point I believe it attempts to serialize the response.

```
{"Error in line 1 position 73. Expecting element 'account' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RecurlyWebApi.Recurly'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'account', namespace ''. "}
```

Here is my HttpClient implementation, simplified for brevity:

```
  public class RecurlyClient
  {
    readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public RecurlyClient()
    {
      var config = (RecurlySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("recurly");

      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.recurly.com/v2/", config.Subdomain));

      // Add the authentication header
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config.ApiKey)));

      // Add an Accept header for XML format.
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    }

    public T Get<T>(string id)
    {
      var accounts = default(T);

      // Make the request and get the response from the service
      HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Concat("accounts/", id)).Result;  // Blocking call!

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        // Parse the response body. Blocking!
        accounts = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
      }

      return accounts;
    }
  }
```

And here is my model:

```
  [XmlRoot("account")]
  public class Account
  {
    [XmlAttribute("href")]
    public string Href { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("account_code")]
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("state")]
    public AccountState State { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("company_name")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("accept_language")]
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("hosted_login_token")]
    public string HostedLoginToken { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
  }
```

And an example of the XML response from the service:

```
<account href="https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/SDTEST01">
  <adjustments href="https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/SDTEST01/adjustments"/>
  <invoices href="https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/SDTEST01/invoices"/>
  <subscriptions href="https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/SDTEST01/subscriptions"/>
  <transactions href="https://mysubdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/SDTEST01/transactions"/>
  <account_code>SDTEST01</account_code>
  <state>active</state>
  <username>myusername</username>
  <email>simon@example.co.uk</email>
  <first_name>First name</first_name>
  <last_name>Last name</last_name>
  <company_name>My Company Name</company_name>
  <vat_number nil="nil"></vat_number>
  <address>
    <address1>My Address Line 1/address1>
    <address2>My Address Line 2</address2>
    <city>My City</city>
    <state>My State</state>
    <zip>PL7 1AB</zip>
    <country>GB</country>
    <phone>0123456789</phone>
  </address>
  <accept_language nil="nil"></accept_language>
  <hosted_login_token>***</hosted_login_token>
  <created_at type="datetime">2013-08-22T15:58:17Z</created_at>
</account>
```

Comment: 'Name' doesn't seem to be a property of the XmlRootAttribute - is this code copied and pasted?

Comment: Hi Polly, that was a typo from when I was preparing my post, I've amended the post now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is because by default the DataContractSerializer is being used to deserialize the XML, and by default the DataContractSerializer uses a namespace of namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace. (In this case Clr.Namepace is RecurlyWebApi.Recurly.)

Because your XML has attributes, you need to use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContractSerializer, and you're set up to do this because your account class is decorated with Xml* attributes. However, you have to use an XmlMediaTypeFormatter which is using the XmlSerializer. You can do this by setting a flag on the global XMLFormatter as described on [this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter):

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

or by supplying a MediaTypeFormatter as a parameter to your ReadAsAsync call:

```
var xmlFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
accounts = response.ReadAsAsync<T>(xmlFormatter).Result
```

Not 100% sure of this because this doesn't explain why the first 'account' in your error message is lower case - the DataContractSerializer should ignore the XmlRoot attribute.

Comment: I had to amend your example slightly as the ReadAsAsync<> method requires a collection so now looks like this..

    response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new Collection<MediaTypeFormatter>() { xmlFormatter }).Result 

However, I still get an exception but this time in the form of {"<account xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Comment: oh dear how confusing. The whole thing might be less obscure if you directly deserialize the object - something like 

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Account));
            Account xmlData = (Account)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(response.OutputStream);

Comment: Hi Polly, due to time restrictions I made a decision to use the RestSharp library and it has proved so much easier to get my project up and running. Should I post that as my answer in order to mark this issue as solved - not sure what is best practice?

Comment: This works:
XmlMediaTypeFormatter xmlFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true };
Task<T> readAsAsync = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> { xmlFormatter });